# boto3 sns delete topic - Invalid parameter

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, client, boto3, amazon-sns

I want to delete topic via python using - https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/sns.html#SNS.Client.delete_topic

when trying this command i get the error: "An error occurred (InvalidParameter) when calling the DeleteTopic operation: Invalid parameter: TopicArn".

My topicArn is legal and exists. I read online and found this may happen because my sns client is not in the same region as the topic, but i couldnt find a way to change one of them via python.

Do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Like all AWS Service Clients in supported Programming languages, you can set the region when you create the Service client. You can perform this task in Python using code like this:

```
ags_west = boto3.client('autoscaling', region_name='us-west-1')
```